# How to enable debug_mode for a JSP page in modern JDeveloper/Weblogic/ADF

Tags: java, weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

For  some reason, instead of target jspx page i am gettin the error

```
OracleJSP error: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Set the init-param debug_mode to "true" to see the complete exception message.
```

(thats it, no file name).

But i have no idea where to set this init-param.

As far as i googled, everyone suggesting (well, back in 2001-2009 years) to set it in `global-web-application.xml` file, but it seems missing in modern JDeveloper setup.

Also ones are suggesting to add init-param in `web.xml` (which is exists), but to non-existing section:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet</servlet-class>
```

So i am confused. Where should i add this init-param in modern (11.1.1.6.0+) JDeveloper setups?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to click the debug icon instead of the run icon in JDeveloper - that will start your WebLogic in debug mode and you'll be able to debug your JSPs.

https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/introduction_to_the_adf_debugger

You can also start WebLogic itself with debug parameters 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/remotedebugwls-086628.html

Answer (score 0):

As Shay mentioned, you could just debug your project instead of running it. To set the debug params, just goto :

```
project properties - run debug - launch settings - java options and add all your params
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option - start Weblogic in debug mode and connect to it using remote debugger from JDeveloper.